# manipulate string with a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got a string named "code" and an int named "lenght" which is the lenght of "code"
also int "todo" which has a value of 0,1 or 2.

0 should delete a character at position "lenght".

1 should change the caracter at position "lenght" to a random character.

2 should add a random charachter at position "lenght".

how do i archive this goal?

```
SET code="%*f0"
set length=0

:loop0
if defined # (
    set #=%#:~1%
    set /A length += 1
    goto loop0
)

SET /A location=%RANDOM% * %lenght% / 32768 + 1
SET /A todo=%RANDOM% * 2 / 32768 + 1

IF %todo% == 0(

)
IF %todo% == 1(

)
IF %todo% == 2(

)
```

Comment: interesting question.generating random character is not so easy in batch and will need a little time to answer this.As a hint [I can give you this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857)

Comment: FWIW You mispelled `%lenght%` and spelt it correctly in the loop `length` so they are different variables.

Answer (score 0):

If correctly understood you, then:

```
@echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "str=%~f0"
    set "len=0"
    set "buf=%str%"

    :loop
    if defined buf (set buf=%buf:~1%& set /a "len+=1" & goto:loop)

    echo Delete char at %%len%% position^:
    set /a "len-=1"
    echo !str:~0,%len%!
    echo.
    echo Change char at %%len%% position for random^:
    rem set chars string
    set "map=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    rem convert it to array
    set "i=0"
    for /l %%i in (0, 1, 25) do (
      for /l %%j in (1, 1, 1) do (
        set "arr.!i!=!map:~%%i,%%j!" & set /a "i+=1"
      )
    )
    rem random set 0..25
    set /a "rnd=0+25*%random%/32768"
    echo !str:~0,%len%!!arr.%rnd%!
  endlocal
exit /b
```